# How to make Git pre-commit behavior depend on commit message?

Tags: git, commit, pre-commit-hook, commit-message

I know that to make git check the commit message before committing you can implement `hooks/commit-msg`. But now imagine a case where you want to let the `hooks/pre-commit` script behave differently based on the commit message?

For example (in a very loose environment) you might want to check whether you have a `[nocheck]` tag in your commit message which always lets your commit-check pass.

Or - in a more strict environment - you might want to have every file commented (and thus listed separately).

Or you might want to check the ticket ID against the related files.

etc...

Is there a way to accomplish this apart from doing the actual check in commit-msg (which seems to be counter-intuitive)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But now imagine a case where you want to let the hooks/pre-commit script behave differently based on the commit message?

This is not possible because there is no commit message when it is fired ...

> The `pre-commit` hook is run first, **before you even type in a commit message**.

---

> Is there a way to accomplish this apart from doing the actual check in `commit-msg` (which seems to be counter-intuitive)?

The way to do it is precisely using `commit-msg` :

> The `commit-msg` hook takes one parameter, which again is the path to a temporary file that contains the current commit message. If this script exits non-zero, Git aborts the commit process, so you can **use it to validate your project state or commit message before allowing a commit to go through**.